# how to send an abi encoded message with Chainlink CCIP?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I want to use a programmable token transfer using Chainlink CCIP.  I want to send a token from Mumbai (source chain) with an function call in another contract on Avalanche (the destination chain).

I tried the token transfer with a string message, that works. But I dont know how to include a function call in the message

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do is pass the target function's "call data" (which will be of the `bytes` data type) as the CCIP message (the data being sent using CCIP).

This require function call encoding.

Here is a great video on how to do that in 3 ways: https://youtu.be/70_2YHJvKIc